# Spin event loop in WebWorker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, worker

I need to spin the loop in a WebWorker. I have dispatched an async method and want to wait for it to complete.

Is there anyway to spin the event loop? So that work continues in the background, but it holds the method from returning, so it is "sync" like.

I tried this and it obviously didn't wok, as it was in the while loop forever:

```
    var lang = fetchFilestoreEntry({ mainkey:'prefs', key:'default_tesseract_lang' }); // <<<<<<< this call is async
    var st = Date.now();
    var i = 0;
    while (!gFilestoreDefault.prefs.quick_save_dir) {
        i++;
    }
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log('prefs__quick_save_dir: took this long to get quick save dir:', (end - st), 'ms', 'ticks:', i);
```

This would get stuck in the while loop forever.

Comment: Where's the async operation?  It should have a callback that tells you when it's done.  You need to use that.  There is no way for you to "spin the event loop" in Javascript.  You finish executing and only when you've done that does the event loop get to run and pull the next event from the queue.  Now, if you're using a webWorker, it has a different event loop from the main JS thread.  The two only communicate via `worker.postMessage()` and messages are only processed when the current thread of JS has finished executing and returned back to the system.

Comment: Aw darn, I was hoping there was a way. Thanks for your quick comment. I updated the code above with a comment next to the async op.

Comment: `fetchFilestoreEntry()` needs a completion callback or it needs to return a promise and you act on that.  That's how this sort of thing works in Javascript.  `fetchFilestoreEntry()` isn't any sort of standard interface so I don't know what it is in order to elaborate further.  Keep in mind there is no background JS execution.  While your `while` loop is spinning, no other JS in this webWorker is able to run.  There can be background native code running, but not background JS.

Comment: @jfriend00 - drats, ok thank you very much!